# Textmeshpro background color

Tags: unity, text-mesh-pro

Trying to get the  tag in text mesh pro to draw the mark color behind the actual text. According to [this](https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-set-text-background-color.570751/) thread it's possible using a workaround where you use the  tag in combination with  to force the font geo to render in front.

Doesn't work for me though. This is the value of my text field: `<mark=#FF80aaaa><font="LiberationSans SDF">test`

I've trie various combinations but it always draws the mark in front of the text.